# Create multiple rows in mysql with parent and loop of children XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm making a Bill Of Materials table. My XML parent node is the product we are making and the children is the BOM lines e.g

```
<BOM>
 <ProductName>This</ProductName>
 <BOMLines>
  <BOMLine>
  <ProductCode>Widget-1</ProductCode>
  <Qty>111</Qty>
  </BOMLine>

  <BOMLine>
  <ProductCode>Widget-2</ProductCode>
  <Qty>222</Qty>
  </BOMLine>

  <BOMLine>
  <ProductCode>Widget-3</ProductCode>
  <Qty>333</Qty>
  </BOMLine>
 </BomLines>
</BOM>
```

My end goal, using PHP to insert a single for row each BOMLine ProductCode along with the parent product info as such;

```
TABLE bom
id      productCode      lineCode       qty
1       PROD-1            Widget-1      111
2       PROD-1            Widget-2      222
3       PROD-1            Widget-3      333
```

This is the code I have so far but I can't get the parent info to work this way;

```
function updateBOM() {
$BOMXml = getBOMs('');

foreach ($BOMXml->BOM->BOMLines->BOMLine as $BOM) {

    $BOMLine = $BOM->ProductCode;
    $BOMQty = $BOM->Qty;
    $ParentProduct = $BOMXML->BOM->ProductName


    $sql = "INSERT INTO bom (productCode, lineCode, Qty) VALUES ('$ParentProduct', '$BOMLine', '$BOMQty')";

    $retval = mysql_query($sql);

        if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    $count += '1';
}
```

Query runs, I get some data, but all the parent product is empty on each row :z

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you in a right way and based on the code you tried,
I believe you can get the parent product by:

```
$BOMXml->BOM->ProductName
```

"before" the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using two declarative, special-purpose languages: XSLT and SQL! Since MySQL provides the facility to directly import XML files to database tables with the [`LOAD XML`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) command, have PHP transform raw XML into a simplified flat structure for MySQL import (where transformed nodes align to column names).

Here you avoid any looping of iterative append queries. To run XSLT 1.0 scripts, PHP requires the `php_xsl` extension enabled in .ini file. Also, do note because `mysql_*` is a deprecated library entirely removed in PHP 7, SQL call uses the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) library assumed to be pre-initialized. Enjoy calling the two engines: libxslt and MySQL!

**PHP** *(with embedded XSLT and SQL code)*

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->loadXML('<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
                <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
                <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

                  <xsl:template match="/BOM">
                    <data>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="BOMLines"/>
                    </data>
                  </xsl:template>

                  <xsl:template match="BOMLine">
                    <row>
                      <productCode><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::BOM/ProductName"/></productCode>
                      <lineCode><xsl:value-of select="ProductCode" /></lineCode>
                      <qty><xsl:value-of select="Qty"/></qty>
                    </row>
                  </xsl:template>

                </xsl:transform>');

// INITIALIZE AND CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);     

// TRANSFORM XML SOURCE
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// SAVE CONTENT TO FILE
file_put_contents('/Output.xml', $newXML);

// RUN SQL COMMAND (IMPORTING FILE WITH FULL PATH REFERENCE)
$mysqli->query("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/Output.xml'
                INTO TABLE bom
                ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';");
```